# Infinite sum of odd-length binary numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binary

Is it possible to find a closed expression for the following sum:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_k^2}$

where $a_k$ is the $k$-th number with its most significant '$1$' at an odd digit place?

A number of this kind is the number $5$, because $5$ in binary is $101_2$, which has its most significant '$1$' at place three. A list of these numbers is given by sequence [A053738](http://oeis.org/A053738).

Comment: That is not $5$ in binary. This is how $5$ is written in binary:
$$101_2$$

Comment: I'm not understanding... when we say something like $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ we usually mean that $k$ is an index variable for the summation and the summation refers to $\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\dots$... here you talk about "*where $k$ is a number with its most significant $1$ at an odd digit place*"... do you mean to do instead the sum $\sum\limits_{k\in K}\frac{1}{k^2}$ where $K$ is the set of numbers with most significant $1$'s at an odd digit place (*in binary*)?

Comment: Yes, I mean the k-th number in the sequence A053738.

Comment: Alternatively, write it as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_k^2}$ where $a_k$ is the $k$'th number with its most significant $1$ at an odd digit place... but don't use $k$ to represent multiple different things in the same sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence $a_k$ consists of the numbers $2^{2j}$ to $2^{2j+1}-1$, for nonnegative integers $j$.  Thus your sum is

$$ \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=2^{2j}}^{2^{2j+1}-1} \frac{1}{i^2} 
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\Psi(1,2^{2j}) -\Psi \left( 1,2^{2j+1} \right)  \right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \Psi(1, 2^k)$$

in Maple's notation.  I don't know of a closed form for the last sum.
Numerically it is approximately $1.1939512459529255006$.  The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au) returns nothing.

Comment: What is the psi-function doing?

Comment: $\Psi(1,x) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \Psi(x)$.  If $x$ is a positive integer, $\Psi(1,x) = \sum_{j=x}^\infty 1/j^2$.